# Combinations without repetition.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have 15 objects and want to choose 9 of them.

What is the difference between $C(15,9)$ and $C(15,3)C(12,3)C(9,3)$? I think both choose 9 out of 15 questions.

This was the first question.

Second question.
If there are 15 questions and there are 3 people and each one should choose 3 questions, what is the probability, that they will choose diffeerent questions? Is it $\frac{C(15,9)}{C(15,3)^3}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On first question:

There is multiple counting in $C(15,3)C(12,3)C(9,3)$. You can e.g. firstly pick out $1,2,3$ as $3$ out of $15$, then $4,5,6$ as $3$ out of the remaining $12$ and thirdly $7,8,9$ as $3$ out of the remaining $9$. The endresult is $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ but is also achieved by firstly $4,5,6$, secondly $7,8,9$ and thirdly $1,2,3$. So result $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ is counted more than once. This multiple counting lacks in $C(15,9)$

On the second question:

There is probability: $$\binom{12}3\binom93\binom{15}3^{-2}$$ that all will choose different questions.

Let's say that they choose one by one.

If the first person has made his choice then the probability that the second will choose different questions is: $\binom{12}3\binom{15}3^{-1}$. If again $3$ other questions have been chosen then the probability that the third will again ask different questions is $\binom93\binom{15}3^{-1}$. These factors must be multiplied to yield the probability.

---

edit (after some puzzling)

Actually $\binom{15}3\binom{12}3\binom93$ is the number of ways to put in each of $3$ distinghuishable boxes exactly $3$ objects. The factor $\binom{15}3$ stands for the number of ways to select $3$ objects for box $A$. Then factor  $\binom{12}3$ for the number of ways to select $3$ objects for box $B$ (out of the remaining $12$) and factor $\binom93$ for the number of ways to select $3$ objects for box $C$ (out of the remaining $9$).

Another route: If $9$ objects are selected, wich can be done on $\binom{15}9$ ways, then there are $\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}$ ways to split up. And indeed: $$\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}\times\binom{15}9=\binom{15}3\binom{12}3\binom93$$

Also note that: $$\binom{15}3\binom{12}3\binom93=\frac{15!}{3!3!3!6!}$$

A split up in $4$ boxes where $3$ of them contain $3$ objects and $1$ contains $6$ objects.

Comment: Your answer is for the second question. What about the first? How do interpret C(15,9) and C(15,3)C(12,3)C(9,3)?

Comment: Regarding first question. You explained clearly, but from your explanation it appears that ratio of C(15,3)C(12,3)C(9,3) and C(15,9) should be 3! (permutation of 3 groups). But in fact it is 1680. Why is that? What makes ratio factor so big?

Comment: The ratio is indeed $\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}=1680$ and at the moment it is for me some puzzle too :)

Comment: There are $\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}=1680$ ways to split up the numbers $1,\dots,9$ into $3$ distinguishable groups of $3$ numbers. There lies the answer! Every split up corresponds with a counting. In $C(15,9)$ there is only one counting of this.

Comment: Fantastic. Now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the first question:

$C(15,9)$ is the number of combination of choosing 9 different objects out of 15 different objects.

$C(15,3)C(12,3)C(9,3)$ is the number of combination of choosing 3 different objects out of 15 different objects of a specific group plus the number of combination of choosing 3 different objects out of 12 different objects of a second specific group plus the number of combination of choosing 3 different objects out of 3 different objects of a third specific group. In total you choose from $36$ objects.

In both cases you do not regard the order.

Comment: Why above two numbers don't equal? What is the connection with them? How to get one number form another? I don't feel the difference.

Comment: @AndrewFount There is no strong connection between the two expressions. The main difference is that you draw 9 objects out of $36 (=15+12+9)$ objects in your second example and 9 objects out of 15 in your first example. Can you see that ?

Comment: There is connection. As @drhab mentioned ratio is 1680 which is $\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}$ - number of ways to split up 9 numbers into 3 distinguashable groups. $C(15,3)C(12,3)C(9,3)$ takes all these groups while $C(15,9)$ counts only one. Thank you all for responses.

Comment: @AndrewFount Quote:"$C(15,3)C(12,3)C(9,3)$ take all these groups ...". Are you aware, that you choose from 36 objects ?

Comment: I actually asked to interpret C(15,3)C(12,3)C(9,3) if we have only 15 objects.